# Create a key pair for a Monero wallet through the seed generator from the BIP32/BIP44 standard

Tags: monero-wallet-gui, privacy, mnemonic-seed, cryptography, privatekey

I am trying to derive my accounts of different blockchains via **BIP44** standard to have deterministic account hierarchy. I was able to generate keys for BTC,ETH and other blockchains, but not for monero yet.

I'm using the **monerojs** library from node.js and the only method I've found that allows me to insert a seed to derive my wallet is the following: [https://moneroecosystem.org/monero-javascript/global.html#createWalletKeys]

But when I go to insert in the parameters the 32byte "seedOffset" generated by these lines of code:

```
const seed = bip39.mnemonicToSeedSync(mnemonic);
const masterNode = bip32.fromSeed(seed);
const path = `m/44'/128'/0'/0/0`;
const child = masterNode.derivePath(path);
let wallet = await monerojs.createWalletKeys({
    networkType: MoneroNetworkType.STAGENET,
    seedOffset: child.privateKey  
  });
```

If I run the console returns me:

```
 if (config.getSeedOffset() !== undefined) throw new MoneroError("Cannot provide seedOffset when creating random wallet");
                                                  ^

MoneroError: Cannot provide seedOffset when creating random wallet
    at Function.createWallet (C:\Users\alexc\OneDrive\Documenti\GitHub\ECDSA-sign\node_modules\monero-javascript\src\main\js\wallet\MoneroWalletKeys.js:63:55)
    at Object.module.exports.createWalletKeys (C:\Users\alexc\OneDrive\Documenti\GitHub\ECDSA-sign\node_modules\monero-javascript\index.js:286:87)
```

Any advice on how to manage this thing and derive in the best way one or more Monero accounts from the same seed as MasterNode BIP44?

Comment: Firstly, a seed *offset* is not a seed. Have you also seen this [comment](https://github.com/monero-ecosystem/monero-javascript/issues/107#issuecomment-1271918701) and linked [example code](https://github.com/monero-ecosystem/monero-javascript#sample-code)?

Comment: Yes, i seen this example code. But the thing I'm missing is how to generate Monero keys so that they are intrinsically linked to masterNode BIP32

Comment: That JS lib (using createWalletKeys or createWalletFull) is allowing you to use the mnemonic seed (words) to construct a wallet, so you're going to need to get the Monero words for your key/seed. As Monero doesn't use bip39, you'll have to juggle the bip39 seed to Monero words before creating the wallet (with Monero words).

Comment: I need this "juggle" to continue. Do you have some examples or tips??

Comment: Take your variable `seed` and convert to Monero mnumonic words, then pass those Monero words into the constructor of the wallet function.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, `seedOffset` is *not* a *seed*.

Secondly, Monero doesn't use BIP 39, so you'll need to convert your BIP 39 `seed` (the result of `bip39.mnemonicToSeedSync` or `child.privateKey`; whichever you prefer), to a Monero mnemonic seed phrase. The `monero-javascript` library doesn't appear to support that, but this step is fairly trivial and there's an example javascript version at [mnemonic.js](https://xmr.llcoins.net/js/mnemonic.js) (`mn_encode`).

Lastly, pass the resulting Monero seed phrase as parameter `mnemonic` in the constructor of `createWalletKeys` (see the [doc](https://moneroecosystem.org/monero-javascript/global.html#createWalletKeys)).

Comment: so you say to insert my child.privatekey as a parameter of the `mn_encode` method? The method requires a string and a wordset_name, the wordset_name is optional right?

Comment: I also run the script and the console says that `crc32` is not defined. in fact in the class this object is not defined. Advice?

Comment: You obviously need to include the other scripts for it to work locally.

Comment: i found the class, but the code want a mnemonic, if i pass `bip39.mnemonicToSeedSync` or `child.privateKey`, doesn't work

Comment: It does work, it's being used extensively by the website (https://xmr.llcoins.net/) hosting it. You have to pass it a hex string.

Comment: Example calling `mn_encode`: https://paste.debian.net/1278090/

Comment: If you try to use the string they use in the [https://paste.debian.net/1278090/](paste.debian) link you sent and put it in [https://xmr.llcoins.net/](xmr.llcoins.net) , If you see, if you enter a hexadecimal string, it returns the same error as me, i.e. : `TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'slice')`

Comment: No, it works fine. The [paste](https://paste.debian.net/1278090/) is from running in my browser console, and here's a [screenshot](https://cdn.imgpaste.net/2023/04/23/KHRcYT.png) using the address test [website](https://xmr.llcoins.net/addresstests.html). (paste string in box 2 and press button "Gen 1".

Comment: I fixed that error that was coming up, I can create an account and derive it through my seed. A thousand thanks!!